# When creating a new thread, changes to GUI are not being made (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

With some help I have managed to create a new thread, although the method appears to execute, the conditions of the method either make a green or red light appear, although when running the method (Check1..etc) without the new thread the changes are reflected on the GUI (e.g. Red / Green Light Appears), but when creating a new thread and running the method the changes are not reflected on the Form / GUI.

```
// Method / Action to start the checks         private void StartChecks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Thread t = new Thread(
               o =>
               {
                   InitChecks();
               });
            t.Start();
        }

// Check1 public void Check1()
        {

            // lets grabs the info from the config!
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines("probe_settings.ini");
            var dictionary = lines.Zip(lines.Skip(1), (a, b) => new { Key = a, Value = b })
                                  .Where(l => l.Key.StartsWith("#"))
                                  .ToDictionary(l => l.Key, l => l.Value);

            // lets set the appropriate value for this check field
            label1.Text = dictionary["#CheckName1"];

            // lets define variables and convert the string in the dictionary to int for the sock.connection method!

            int portno1;
            int.TryParse(dictionary["#PortNo1"], out portno1);

            // Convert hostname to IP, performance issue when using an invalid port on a hostname using the TcpClient class! 
            IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostname2);

            foreach (IPAddress theaddress in addresslist)
            {
                // Attempt to create socket and connect to specified port on host
                TcpClient tcP = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
                try
                {
                    tcP.ReceiveTimeout = 1;
                    tcP.SendTimeout = 1;
                    tcP.Connect(theaddress, portno1);
                    displayGreen1();
                    tcP.Close();
                }
                catch
                {
                    displayRed1();
                }
            }

        }

// Change the lights when the condition is met

        public void displayGreen1()
        {
            pictureBox2.Visible = false;
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        }

        private void displayRed1()
        {
            pictureBox2.Visible = true;
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because UI controls can only be updated from the UI thread. When you *do not* create a new thread, the code which updates the controls runs on the UI thread, so it works as you expect. When you *do* create a new thread, because this thread *is not* the UI thread, the code which is supposed to update the controls fails to do so.

You can ensure that the code which updates the controls runs on the UI thread by changing the method calls to:-

```
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => displayRed1()));
```

and

```
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => displayGreen1()));
```

---

Incidentally (unrelated to your current problem):-

Try to avoid creating an explicit thread. Instead use the thread pool to manage the thread for you, e.g. `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>  InitChecks())`. (Note that this will still run on a non-UI thread so you still need to use `BeginInvoke()` as detailed above.). The thread pool knows best about when to create and execute a thread and using it will, ultimately, make your code more efficient.

Try to avoid catching *all* exception types in your `try{...}catch{...}`. This is stating that your code knows what to do when *any* type of exception is thrown. Instead, only catch exceptions which you know exactly how to handle,

e.g.

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch(TcpException)
{
    ...
}
catch(AnotherKnownException)
{
    ...
}
...
```

Note that it is OK to also have a `catch` block for *all* exception types as long as you rethrow the exception when exiting the block,

e.g.

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch(KnownException)
{
    ...
}
catch(Exception)
{
    // perform some logging, rollback, etc.
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how WinForms is designed. You can't make changes from another thread.
the solution usually is to use asynchronous delegate.

First of all add this declaration

```
 public delegate void MyDelegate1 ();

 public delegate void MyDelegate2 ();
```

Then When you are in another thread You should do:

```
MyDelegate1 d1= new MyDelegate1 (displayGreen1);

 this.BeginInvoke(d1);

 MyDelegate2 d2= new MyDelegate2 (displayRed1);

 this.BeginInvoke(d2);
```

Answer (score 2):

At your skill level, it would be best to:

- use timer in the form to check some status variable (say `bool _pb1Visible` and `bool _pb2Visible`)
- in the timer event update picturebox visibility
- in the thread, update ONLY bool member variables mentioned above.

It will work like a charm!

Simple example:

In your `Check1()` method, instead of:

```
displayGreen1();
```

put

```
_pb1Visible=true;
_pb1Visible=false;
```

and instead of

```
displayRed1();
```

put

```
_pb1Visible=false;
_pb1Visible=true;
```

Put the timer on the form.  In the timer event, do the:

```
pictureBox2.Visible = _pb2Visible;
pictureBox1.Visible = _pb1Visible;
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you please provide a simple example

Comment: @JamesTeare I added an example for you, hope it will help.